# multiple htaccess redirects to a new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect an entire domain over to another domain while also redirecting a couple of specific pages to specific locations. I also want to preserve www and https on the original domain to ensure there are no errors on the old domain and any links will still work/redirect correctly.

Here's what I've got so far -- the https, www, and sitewide redirect work fine, but the page to page redirect(s) don't do anything:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Force HTTPS and WWW 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.OLDSITE.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?OLDPOST1/?(.*)$ https://NEWSITE.com/NEWPOST1/ [L,QSA,R=302]
RewriteRule ^/?OLDPOST2/?(.*)$ https://NEWSITE.com/NEWPOST2/ [L,QSA,R=302]
RewriteRule ^/?OLDPOST3/?(.*)$ https://NEWSITE.com/NEWPOST3/ [L,QSA,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(.*) https://NEWSITE.com [L,QSA,R=302]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the actual URLs of the "specific pages" you are trying to redirect? Does the new domain point to a different server? The "sitewide redirect" redirects everything to the homepage of the newsite - is that intentional? It makes no sense to "preserve www and https on the original domain" when you are redirecting everything to a new domain anyway. (?)

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite. The specific pages are OLDPOST1 and NEWPOST1 etc in the above example. I'm trying to redirect those specific pages to new pages on the new domain, and then redirect everything else to the homepage. The new site is on the same server just a different domain. I think I misunderstood the need to keep https/www so I've removed that section.

Comment: But what is the "actual URL"? And what is the "actual regex" you are using to match against this URL? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files or directives in the server config? Assuming there are no other directives, the only reason for these "page to page redirects to **not do anything**" is if the regex `^/?OLDPOST1/?(.*)$` does not match the URL you are requesting. This regex is certainly unnecessarily complex if you are matching a specific URL and it would seem to match "too much", but it should match `OLDPOST1` if that string occurs at the very start of the URL-path.

Comment: "The new site is on the same server just a different domain." - By "server", I really mean "filesystem". If both domains point to the same area of the filesystem then you could have problems if the old and new domains are _similar_. To clarify, is the `.htaccess` file located in the document root of the old domain?

Comment: Thanks for your help @MrWhite, I think I was making it overly complex for a possible marginal benefit so have just gone with basic 301 redirects for the moment which are working fine.